# React useEffect inifinite loop when lifting state and state modifier

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component which lifts its state and the state modifier to the parent:

```
export default function DamageInput({ data, onChange }){

    const [qty, setQty] = useState(data?.qty || null);
    const [selectedSize, setSelectedSize] = useState(data?.size || null);
    const [selectedSuppl, setSelectedSuppl] = useState(data?.suppl || []);

    useEffect(() => {

        if(!selectedSize) onChange(null);

        else {

            const damageObject = {
                
                qty: qty,
                size: selectedSize,
                suppl: selectedSuppl
            }

            onChange(damageObject);

        }

    }, [selectedSize, qty, selectedSuppl, onChange]);

    ...
```

The parent which consumes the component:

```
<DamageInput onChange={(damageObject) => handleDamageChange('bonnet', damageObject)} data={data.damage.bonnet} />
```

And the handler function:

```
const handleDamageChange = (panel, damageObject) => {

        if(!damageObject){

            if(data.damage[panel]){

                setData(prevState => {

                    const damageCopy = {...prevState.damage};
                    delete damageCopy[panel];
    
                    return {...prevState, damage: damageCopy};
    
                });

            }

        }

        else setData(prevState => ({...prevState, damage: {...prevState.damage, [panel]: damageObject}}));
    
    };
```

The problem is that as soon as the onChange function called with the damageObject parameter, it causes an infinite loop in the first useEffect. I think the problem is that i had to pass the onChange function as a dependency and it changes every time when rerenders because i pass an "anonymus function" with a parameter to the onChange event. Im stuck for hours now and couldnt find the answer. Thank you

Comment: Why do you need the same state in parent and in children?

Comment: because i made a form which can be a new or update form which needs to accept data if it exists on update form

Comment: Ok, but it seems like you update the data on every key press. I would understand a separate state if the data was updated on a button click. I would just remove the state from the child

Comment: The code you have written will precisely cause an infinite loop. 
What you are doing is passing the props to the child component and on change (useEffect in this case) of these props triggering the onChange again from within the child component, which updates the props in the parent and again in the children and hence the infinite loop. 
Few questions before answering:
1. When should the onChange event in DamangeInput get triggered exactly? 
Is there an input field in the DamageInput component?

2. What is the use of data props in the DamageInput? Are you populating some default values?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. The onChange event should fire every time the data changes(to update the state in parent) in the DamageInput component. There is an input field in the DamageInput component. And yes, data prop should be used if a form is an update type(one form, new or update based on a prop). Thank you